# Binomial theorem on an expression

Tags: number-theory

In my book it said "For nonnegative integers $a,n,$ and $N$ we have that $$(1+Na^{n+1})^a = 1+a \cdot Na^{n+1}+\binom{a}{2}N^2a^{2n+2}+Ma^{3n+3}$$ for some integer $M$." Shouldn't it be $$(1+Na^{n+1})^a = 1+\binom{a}{1} \cdot Na^{n+1}+\binom{a}{2}N^2a^{2n+2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}N^{a}a^{an+a}?$$

Answer (score 1):

In the second term the $a \choose 1$ is just $a$.

For the fourth through last terms, factor out $a^{3n+3}$. The coefficient will be an integer $M$ whose exact value doesn't matter in this argument.